# Sql select multiple rows in joined table and put in same listview record

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I have a sql statement that populates listview. One of my joined tables, has multiple records, that I want to go into the same listview record, NOT a separate record for each item in the joined table. For example, currently, I get 7 records or rows returned in the listview with the below data. But I want only 6 records returned, grouping the photos with the same topicId into the same record.

Select * from topic LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos On Topic.TopicId = Photos.TopicId

If I do Select * from topic LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos On Topic.TopicId = Photos.TopicId And Topic.PhotoId = Photos.PhotoId, then I get only the 1st photo.

I want to return 6 rows: Row 1 having 3 photos, row 2 and row 3 having no photos, row 4 having 3 photos, row 5 having no photos, and row 6 having 1 photo.

```
topic table
topicId  topic    photoId
   1       abc       1
   2       def       null
   3       ghi       null
   4       jkl       4
   5       mno       null
   6       pqr       7
```

then the photos

```
photos table                                   
photoid    topicId   photoname
   1         1          bla
   2         1          bla
   3         1          bla
   4         4          bla
   5         4          bla
   6         4          bla
   7         6          bla
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Tables are flat, meaning you can't fill a 'cell' with anything like an array, which _seems_ to be what you are wanting. Perhaps there is some trickiness that someone will come up with, but it may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit unclear on how you want the data to look, but you can for example return the `photoid` of several photos at once using some XML trickery;

```
SELECT topic.topicid, topic.topic, 
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(photoid AS VARCHAR) 
              FROM photos
              WHERE photos.topicid=topic.topicid
              FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') photos
FROM topic
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c00d6/6).

Comment: although it works on fiddle, on my listview, i get this error: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'PhotoId'.